# Flash Socket Policy

Tags: flash, websocket, policy

When I'm trying to connect to my websocket, it says that flash socket policy is missing, what should I do?

```
[WebSocket] cannot connect to Web Socket server at ws://example.com:10081/ (SecurityError: Error #2048) make sure the server is running and Flash socket policy file is correctly placed 
[WebSocket] closed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need provide Flash socket policy file for your application. If you are using Apache you can use this module: http://socketpolicyserver.com/